# How do I fix this error we get when we are fetching data from API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am coding in TypeScript and making a react quizapp and I am using this API https://the-trivia-api.com/v2/questions everything is correct but instead of the question what gets rendered is `[object Object]` can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

I am getting this error:

> react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.  Check the render method of `QuestionCard`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.     at div     at QuestionCard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/b

This is the code in my API.ts file :

```
import { promises } from "dns";
import { shuffleArray } from "./utils";
export type Question = {
  category: string;
  correctAnswer: string;
  difficulty: string;
  incorrectAnswers: string[];
  question: string;
  type: string;


}

export type QuestionState = Question & {answers: string[]}

export enum Difficulty{
  EASY = "easy",
  MEDIUM = "medium",
  HARD = "hard",
}

 export const fetchQuizQuestions = async (amount: number, difficulty: Difficulty) => {
  const endpoint = `https://the-trivia-api.com/v2/questions?amount=${amount}&difficulty=${Difficulty}&type=multiple`;
  const data = await (await fetch(endpoint)).json();
 
  return data.map((question: Question)=>({
    ...question,
    answers: shuffleArray([...question.incorrectAnswers, question.correctAnswer]),
  }))
 }
```

and this is the code for my App.tsx file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { QuestionCard } from './components/QuestionCard';
import { fetchQuizQuestions } from './API';
import { QuestionState, Difficulty } from './API';
type AnswerObject = {
  questions: string;
  answer: string;
  correct: boolean;
  correctAnswer: string;
}
const TOTAL_QUESTIONS = 10;
const App = () => {

 

 const[loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 const[questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionState[]>([]);
 const[number,setNumber] = useState(0);
 const[userAnswer,setUserAnswer] = useState<AnswerObject[]>([]);
 const[score, setScore] = useState(0);
 const[gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(true);
 console.log(questions);

  const startQuiz = async () => {
   setLoading(true);
   setGameOver(false);

   const newQuestions = await fetchQuizQuestions(
    TOTAL_QUESTIONS,
    Difficulty.EASY
   );
   setQuestions(newQuestions);
   setScore(0);
   setUserAnswer([]);
   setNumber(0);
   setLoading(false);
  }
  const checkAnswer = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {

  }

  const nextQuestion = () => {

  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React quiz</h1>
      {gameOver || userAnswer.length === TOTAL_QUESTIONS ? (
        <button className='start' onClick={startQuiz}>
        start
      </button>
      ): null}
      
     {!gameOver ? <p className='score'>Score:</p>: null}
      {loading && <p>Loading questions</p>}
      {!loading && !gameOver && (
      <QuestionCard 
      questionNr={number + 1} 
      totalQuestions={TOTAL_QUESTIONS} 
      question={questions[number].question}
      answers={questions[number].answers}
      userAnswer={userAnswer? userAnswer[number]: undefined}
      callBack={checkAnswer} 
      />)}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with some modification in fetchQuizQuestions function to ensure that it correctly maps the API response to your QuestionState type. Also, make sure to handle any errors that may occur during the API request.

```
export const fetchQuizQuestions = async (amount: number, difficulty: Difficulty) => {
  try {
    const endpoint = `https://the-trivia-api.com/v2/questions?amount=${amount}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`;
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch questions');
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    return data.results.map((question: Question) => ({
      ...question,
      answers: shuffleArray([...question.incorrect_answers, question.correct_answer]),
    })) as QuestionState[];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching quiz questions:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the help i found out the issue basically the i was directly rendering the questions field but actually it was an object in the api and had text as its property so i modified the code accordingly and it started rendering the questions thanks for the help though  :)